# How to assign different color to different event in Calendar Kit in iOS Swift

Tags: eventkit, ekeventstore, ekeventkit, calendarkit

I want to achieve a task in which i want to add different colors for different events using **Calendar Kit** pod.

[image]

Comment: Please, add a bit of code you're using with CalendarKit.

Otherwise, refer to the code in CalendarApp here: https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarApp/blob/master/Calendar/EKWrapper.swift#L48

So, just make a bridge between the `EKEvent` and `CalendarKit.EventDescriptor` as shown in the EventWrapper.swift code